# is there a TypeScript equivalent of Python's from typing import TYPE_CHECKING?

Tags: python, typescript, typescript-typings

I am trying to deal with a circular import solely because of type checking, hence I was wondering if there was a TypeScript equivalent of Python's `from typing import TYPE_CHECKING` ?

Comment: no, the type system of TypeScript does not exist at runtime because it transform to JavaScript after compile

Comment: @Jerryh001 then surely the TypeScript compiler could remove those if statements from the output? That justification doesn't make sense.